# Building iPod-like menu

Tags: qt, qml

I'm relatively new to QML and need a bit of help.  I have to create an iPod-like menu that displays a main menu with an artist menu, track menu, and album menu.  I thought about using the same ListView for each model and then just swapping the models out dynamically, but QML does not allow me to do this (it looks like you have to add and remove each element yourself).

Another solution I came up with is just load different ListViews with corresponding models using the Loader but I'd like to re-use the same ListView because the only thing that is changing is the content.

Also, I have to do this in strictly QML.  There is a C++ part of it; however, that is just to render the QML and that's it.  Does anyone have any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* change the model of a `ListView` runtime.

Try the following code:

```
Item {
  width: 1000
  height: 250

  ListView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: model1

    delegate: Component{
      Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        Text {text: value; anchors.centerIn: parent}
      }
    }
  }

  ListModel {
    id: model1
    ListElement {value: "A"}
    ListElement {value: "B"}
    ListElement {value: "C"}
  }

  ListModel {
    id: model2
    ListElement {value: "1"}
    ListElement {value: "2"}
    ListElement {value: "3"}
  }

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      console.log("model2")
      view.model = model2
    }
  }
}
```